# When fetching object null pointer error when looking at a field of the class

Tags: java, hibernate, class, object

When entering a staff Id I want to fetch the nurse's name, the staff class can have either doctors or nurse's in it, For e.g is the staffID is equal to 1 it will be a doctor not a nurse, but when I do the same for a nurse's ID it returns a null pointer error.

```
staff.getNurse().getLastName();
```

returns null pointer error

```
The get nurse command in the staff class
public Nurse getNurse() {
        return nurse;
    }
```

Creating the Staff

```
 public Staff(Doctor doctor, Nurse nurse){
        this.doctor = doctor;
        this.nurse = nurse;
    }
```

Nurse is just a class with basic fields in like first name and last name store as Strings

I want to check where the staff is a nurse or doctor and if so get their name and set it to nurseDocName and thier work title to the string title

```
Staff staff = new Staff();
//staffID is set via an input from a JTextarea
staff = sM.getStaff(staffID);
String nurseDocName = "";
String title = "Nurse ";
if(staff.getDoctor().equals(null)) nurseDocName = staff.getNurse().getLastName();
else
{
nurseDocName = staff.getDoctor().getLastName();
title = "Doctor ";
}
```

get staff method in my session manager hibernate class

```
 public Staff getStaff(Integer staffID){
        Session session = factory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;
        Staff staff = new Staff();
        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            staff = session.get(Staff.class, staffID);
        }catch (HibernateException e){
            if(tx != null) tx.rollback();
        }
        session.close();
        return staff;
    }
```

Soloution changed .equals to ==

```
if(staff.getDoctor() == null) nurseDocName = staff.getNurse().getLastName();
```

Comment: In the above code you are calling `new Staff()` but how/where is the Nurse object set  ? is `getStaff(staffID)` makes a DB call and sets the Nurse object ?

Comment: `getLastName().equals(null)` doesn't make sense: if getLastName() returns null, then it will cause a NullPointerException, becase you an't call a method on null. Use `==` to compare something with null.

Comment: getStaff is a method in my hibernate class that get's the staff object from a database, I have added this to the original post @Sachin

Comment: As mentioned by @galando you need to make a null check on `Nurse` object within `Staff` class before accessing its fields.